# JS: Using changing String in command after "."

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms, for-loop

Currently I'm trying out some html and js stuff.
I have trouble using a changing string inside a command with some "." in it.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    let count = String("q" + i);
    console.log(document.calculate.$(this.count).value);
}
```

So the String "count" is changing and I want the different values of my document with the names "q1", "q2"...

Would be awesome if someone could help me.
Thank You!

Comment: ["bracket notation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Thanks. That worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put dinamic value in a `[]` quotes instead `.`

`console.log(document.calculate[$(this.count)].value);`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 1; i<=2; i++) {
  let count = String("q" + i);
  console.log(document.calculate.$(this[count]).value);
}
```